# How do I change the lock screen using a batch file?

Tags: windows-10, batch, automation, lock-screen

I know how to change a lock screen image using the personalization settings.

I have a room full of computers which are re-imaged regularly, over which I have no control, so I looking for something which does the job simply.

After a student enters <kbd>win</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> I would like to show a message.

Is there a way I can either add a text message or change the screen image via a batch file?

Answer (score 0):

How to add text to login screen, not 100% sure if it'll show at lock screen when a user is logged in.

1. Local Group Policy
2. Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options - Interactive Login Text

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/interactive-logon-message-text-for-users-attempting-to-log-on

Comment: I’ve tried that. It doesn’t appear after a Win-L, only after startup.